# Using Client Certificate to get SOAP server WSDL file

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ssl, soap, wsdl

I am new to SSl and WCF. I have been trying to figure this out for a while now, and I read all relevant question I could find on Stack Overflow. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I am currently writing a client for a SOAP Server that uses SSL client certificate for authentication. I am trying to access the WSDL file to generate a proxy for my client. However, I keep having "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." when I try to access the file.

Here are the step I did:

1. Created a root CA certificate using: 
   makecert -n "CN=RootCATest" -r -sv RootCATest.pvk RootCATest.cer
2. Installed the Root CA Certificate on my machine using MMC
3. Created and Install Temporary Service Certificate using : 
   makecert -sk MyKeyName -iv RootCATest.pvk -n "CN=tempCert" -ic RootCATest.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe
4. I send the "tempCert.cer" file to the server owner who installed it on theserver

After that I still can't access the serverUrl.com/services/info?wsdl

Can anyone help me on this?

**Edit:**

I only own the client. The server is hosted by someone else and I don't know what technology is used there. They provided me a url to their wsdl file and they asked me to give them a certificate for client authentication. They installed that certificate on the server.

I want to use the "Add Service Reference" or SvcUtil.exe to generate a proxy with configurations (and then add my certificate to the config after). But for that I need access to the WSDL file.

I am wondering if I send them the right certificate? Should I have send the self-signed root CA certificate I used to create my certificate?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more details like, do you own both client and service? where did you host your service (self-hosted, iis, windows service)? Can you post your configuration on how you access the certificate from store?

Comment: does your service is working properly prior of implementing ssl?

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it answer your questions. Thanks for the help, it is really appreciated

Comment: hmm, first who ever own the server should be the one that will give the certificate to the client, not the client. What was the reason why are the client will give the certification to server/service? If it's a production buy a legit certification to certificate authority. Main issue is security risk.

Comment: ok. I will ask the server team if the can give a certificate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the only step I was missing was to send the Root CA certificate to their server also. Once it was installed on their server, my self-generated certificate validated properly. This is not a good solution for production, but it worked well during development.